# C# how to populate a string, IList, or Array through if statement

Tags: c#

I have the following code:

```
foreach (string file in FleName)
            if (!ActualFiles.Any(x => Path.GetFileName(x).Equals(file)))
            {                   
                  IList<string> MissingFiles = file;
            }
```

I have 3 if statements that access this method. At the end of the if statements I need to show the entire IList.

So heres what I want. First if statment goes into the method and returns every file with the word "EqpFle -" before each value

The second if statemenet I want it to return all those items with "DPFle-" in front of all the names, and simialr for the third.

At the end of all the if statements (this is in a for each) I want it to read the entire list.

how owuld I do this?

the ifs basically look as follows:

```
    foreach (string file in files)
    {
    if
    {
    Check <----thats the method
    }
    if
    {
    Check <----thats the method
    }
    if
    {
    Check <----thats the method
    }
    }
```

Comment: the LINQ `Except` method looks like a faster and clearer version of your first code-snippet. I don't understand the rest of the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not entirely clear exactly what's going on here - but basically if you create an empty list to start with and pass it *into* the method as an argument, the method can add the new entries to it.

This would almost certainly be simpler with LINQ (probably using `Concat`, and a method which returned an `IEnumerable<string>` of files matching a given pattern), but it's not entirely obvious what you're trying to do, which makes it hard to suggest a LINQ approach.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to Jon's answer (of passing in the List to your method), you might also be able to just yield your results as required....

```
foreach(string file in files)
{
  if(**condition**)
  {
    yield return file;
  }
  if(**condition**)
  {
    yield return file;
  }
  if(**condition**)
  {
    yield return file;
  }
}
```